# Qt platform plugin Error in runnig container. how to show open cv output image with docker container on linux?

Tags: docker, qt, opencv, dockerfile, docker-image

I wanna create a docker image on windows and image base [in docker file] for docker image would be linux os. My program uses the open-cv program which its output image has to be shown with `CV2.imshow()`. but after running container, I get this error.

please help to fix it.

```
qt.qpa.xcb: could not connect to display
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cv2/qt/plugins" even though it was found.
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

Available platform plugins are: xcb.
```

Comment: Error is accured during run container.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had this same issue and none of the solutions I looked up solved the issue for me. I even used `xhost +` and imshow still did not work.

I was using the image tensorflow/tensorflow:2.7.0-gpu as my base image for my project. Seems like the package `libsm6` is missing for some reason, and doing `apt install libsm6` made it work.

Hope this helped!

Comment: apt install libsm6?

Answer (score 0):

I also had this issue. The one solution that finally worked was to install an earlier version of opencv-python. The version I had originally installed was 4.6.0.66. I uninstalled opencv `pip uninstall opencv-python` in docker and reinstalled `RUN pip install opencv-python==4.1.2.30` in the dockerfile.

Comment: How it work? Can you explain more?